# Error reading Excel document in forms C#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I'm trying to take XLSX data and putting it into an DataGridView using the ExcelDataReader NuGet package. 
But i get a Object reference not set to an instance of an object error on line 35

```
foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
```

Here is the full code.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using Excel;

namespace MyForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataSet result;

        private void butOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    cboSheet.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                    cboSheet.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    reader.Close();

                }
            }

        }

        private void cboSheet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = result.Tables[cboSheet.SelectedIndex];

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error message: 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXU65.png)

Comment: You get the error because `reader.AsDataSet()` returns null and you're trying to access the property `result.Tables`. Do you have an example of a .xlsx file to test this with?

Comment: Probably your dataset `result` is taking null content. Try to debug and see what is the content of  `result`. Also try to instantiate as `DataSet result = new DataSet()`

Comment: This seems to be an issue with newer .xlsx files. The IExcelDataREader object contains an error message indicating problems with the file signature. When i updated the package to the latest  prerelease version (v3.0.0-develop00086) and added the package `ExcelDataREader.DataSet` (now required to use the `AsDataSet()` extension method) i was able to read a xlsx file and access the tables in the dataset.

Comment: So you are saying i need to update the NuGet package?

Comment: The latest version is a prerelease. If you're willing to use a package explicitly marked as prerelease in a production environment, yes, that would be an option. Otherwise you'll either have to wait for a "finished" version of the package or find another solution that completely avoids the nuget package.

Comment: @ThomasEggemann. Okay, thank you for your help. I do still have an issues with the reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true; not having a definition.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the comments:

The property `IsFirstRowAsColumnNames` is no longer available on newer versions of the package.

From the GitHub page [LINK](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader):

> **AsDataSet configuration options**
>
> The AsDataSet() function accepts an optional configuration object to
>   modify the behavior of the DataSet conversion:

```
var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() {

    // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to set the DataColumn.DataType 
    // property in a second pass.
    UseColumnDataType = true,

    // Gets or sets a callback to obtain configuration options for a DataTable. 
    ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() {

        // Gets or sets a value indicating the prefix of generated column names.
        EmptyColumnNamePrefix = "Column",

        // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to use a row from the 
        // data as column names.
        UseHeaderRow = false,

        // Gets or sets a callback to determine which row is the header row. 
        // Only called when UseHeaderRow = true.
        ReadHeaderRow = (rowReader) => {
            // F.ex skip the first row and use the 2nd row as column headers:
            rowReader.Read();
        }
    }
});
```

I'm guessing that the line `UseHeaderRow = true;` in the `ExcelDataTAbleConfiguration` would result in the wanted behavior.

**EDIT: Add working example**

This example works for me with a new .xlsx file created in Excel 2016.
The file contains two sheets: Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Both contain two columns with two rows of text.

```
List<string> tblNames = new List<string>();
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

if (ofd.ShowDialog() ?? false)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(fs))
        {
            var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
            {
                UseColumnDataType = true,

                ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                {                                
                    UseHeaderRow = true
                }
            });

            foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                tblNames.Add(dt.TableName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a WPF application, so the usage of `OpenFileDialog` looks a bit different.

Comment: Okay, I'm now getting a invalid file signature error caused by line 31, IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);

Comment: Which software (and version) did you use to create the .xlsx file?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2016

Comment: Can you create a new .xlsx file with Excel Online and try it with the new file? I'm curious if the files behave differently. I'm currently not able to reproduce this.

Comment: Using Excel online, i downloaded a copy of the book and it crashed in the same way.